# How to edit Settings.bundle in XCode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2, settings.bundle

**Problem** : Quite simply, in my iOS app I have a Settings.bundle to help create the settings page. In XCode 3 I could simply edit this, but it doesn't seem possible in XCode 4. Settings.bundle can't be opened from XCode and going through the folders myself I can't see a file to edit. What do I do?

**Screenshot of Settings.bundle in XCode 4.2** :

[image]

**Update - Screenshot of structure in Finder** :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode 4.2 select your Settings.bundle; Show Utilities; In the Identity & Type Utility, change file type to CoreFoundation.bundle.

Comment: Aha! Nice! I've never tried this before on Stack Overflow, but I'm changing my winning answer to this one, for this doesn't involve leaving XCode and going to Finder.

Answer (score 1):

Right click settings bundle in the project navigator >> show in finder >> right click settings bundle in finder >> hit "show package contents" >> edit the plist as you like!

Comment: Haha, you've pretty much just copied my own answer and added a tiny little extra bit of advice at the start, but sure, I'll give you the green tick! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it, although it bypasses XCode. In Finder, right click on Settings.bundle, and choose 'Show Package Contents'. Then edit as necessary.